# Eliminate borders for automatic license plate recognition

Tags: python, image-processing, computer-vision

Im working on a ALPR system, from the binarization part the images endup with a border that prevent the OCR to get the correct values.

As in this image:

[image]

How can I delete the black border an get only the characters?

EDIT.

This is the input:

[image]

That's the quality of the images.

Comment: you should provide the input image. it is very likely that you should improve things in earlier steps.

Comment: @Piglet I added the input.

Comment: for this particular image extract the green channel and do a global threshold. this will give you the letters. in general I'd go for some template matching or machine learning based approach. binarization is not necessary. and increase the resolution and don't use compressed jpegs. get a proper monochrome camera... that image is aweful.

Comment: @Piglet I can't change the camera. I'll try the global threshold.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The resolution is at the limit of what is reasonable.

You can improve a little by

- doubling the resolution (bilinear interpolation),
- applying a top-hat morphological filter,
- binarizing.

[image]

Comment: @LuisRamonRamirezRodriguez: this was obtained with mViz by VISION fOr VISION, a commercial package.